# Save/update widget outside admin panel

Tags: widgets, sidebar

Is there some way to update/save widget from page - not from admin ?

I create widget with charts and do not know how to update it from sidebar. I found of course form in admin:

```
<form action="" method="post">

  <input type="submit" name="savewidget" id="widget-chart_widget-2-savewidget" 
     class="button button-primary widget-control-save right" value="Save">
```

But what is this ID = widget-chart_widget-2-savewidget ... how this ID is created?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? More context would help here.